# Insert SQL data into table by copying values from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables and trying to insert data into table T2 by copying from the same table if the name is Similar.

For Example, If T2 Has Name Red Then Copy ID and Name from T1 along with T2 Field.

TABLE T1

```
  ID| NAME
  5   RED T
  6   BLUE T
```

TABLE T2

```
  ID| NAME| FIELD 1| FIELD 2|FIELD 3
  1   RED   17       20      23
  2   RED   10       15      9
  3   BLUE  7        8       3
```

EXPECTED OUTCOME:

```
  TABLE T3
  ID| NAME| FIELD 1| FIELD 2|FIELD 3
  1   RED   17       20      23
  1   RED   10       15      9
  5   RED T 17       20      23
  5   RED T 10       15      9
  3   BLUE T 7        8       3
  6   BLUE T 7        8       3
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  Insert into T1
  Select ID, Name, Field1, Field2, Field3 From T2 a
  Left Join T1 b
  On a.Name like b.name
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Define similar.

Comment: Similar is Like %%

Comment: UUmmm....that doesn't make this any clearer. RED and RED T are similar? You need to define some sort of rule as to what is similar. Is RED and DRED similar?

Comment: Sorry, Any name has the word Red in it.

Comment: So DRED, RED, FRED, TIRED, REDUCED are all the same? Help us to help you. Give us some details. I know you understand what you want but we don't.

Comment: And looking at your example you don't have any wildcards. Which side do you want them?

Comment: Sean: Thanks. I appreciate your help. To answer your question , DRED, RED, FRED, TIRED, REDUCED can be considered the same.

Comment: Wildcards would have to be on T1

Comment: Then given your sample you have none that are similar because none of the values in TABLE 2 have the value "RED T" or "BLUE T". Either move the wildcard to the other table or redefine similar.

Comment: It's unclear what criteria should be used for filling the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned inserting into T2 but results displayed T3 so I went with T3 for now.  If you really only want the records that weren't already in T2 then you can omit the UNION to the second part. Since you said that 'containing' is the same as 'similar' for your purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (5, 'RED T');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (6, 'BLUE T');

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20),
    FIELD1 INT,
    FIELD2 INT,
    FIELD3 INT
);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1,'RED',17,20,23);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2,'RED',10,15,9);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (3,'BLUE',7,8,3);

INSERT INTO T3(ID, NAME, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.NAME, T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.NAME LIKE '%'||T2.NAME||'%'
UNION
SELECT T2.ID, T2.NAME, T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3
FROM T2
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO T2 ([NAME], FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) 
SELECT T1.NAME, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.NAME LIKE CONCAT("%", T2.NAME ,"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due the the fact that `'RED T'` is not `like` `'RED'`

You could try

```
  Insert into T1
  Select ID, Name, Field1, Field2, Field3 From T2 a
  Left Join T1 b
  On a.Name like ('%' + b.name + '%')
```

...But this is not generic or at least it could not match all the cases you would expect. 
As others said you should specify more clearly what you mean by *"similar"*.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the possible query

```
Insert into T1 (ID, Name, Field1, Field2, Field3) 
Select t.ID, t.Name, t2.Field1, t2.Field2, t2.Field3 
From T1 t Left outer join T2 t2 on  
substring(t.Name,1,CHARINDEX(' ', t.Name))=t2.Name
```

Apologies for possible syntax mismatch as I didn't execute it and entered the solution via phone

The solution I have proposed is based on the assumption that in T1 the matching colour should be the first part then a space and finally last part